# CURL unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, post, curl

I have this page that I'm going a CURL POSTing some info to another site of mine, but I have a error and I can't find the cause.

The error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/aaran/public_html/tests/will/1.php on line 13

(that's the line with the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS on).

Here's the URL to see the script: http://hm.vc/tests/will/1.php

The script:

```
<?php
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
    $input[$key] = urldecode(strip_tags($value));
}

$secureurl = "http://hm.vc/tests/will/2.php";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $secureurl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $input);
                
$hello = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);


echo "Hi " . $input['name'] . ", Thanks for blah blah blah blah";
?>
```

Comment: Your script works for me. -- edit -- nevermind. Can you dump the $input right before $secureurl is set?

Comment: To make the script interpret well to see what $input is holding, just comment the setopt with POSTFIELDS.

Comment: A syntax error means the code could not be tokenised. It has more to do with how you wrote it than how it runs.

Comment: Do any of your get parameters happen to have dashes in their keys?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, works fine for me. Please post an example that actually shows this behavior.

Comment: PHP is notorious for choking on special characters or issues with encoding. Make sure your file isn't hiding a non-printing or control character somewhere.

Comment: This can close as lacking an [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't know what data you're using in the `$_GET` array, I can only guess, but as mentioned already, do a `print_r($input)` after creating it to see exactly what data you're passing.

It seems that using an array for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` requires that all values be scalar. If one of your `$_GET` variables is an array, you might be running into a problem. See the comments at http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php, specifically 28-Jul-2010, which states:

> Be careful when setting the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` setting using an array. The array used to set the POST fields must only contain scalar values. Multidimentional arrays or objects lacking a __toString implementation will cause Curl to error.
>
> If there is a need to send non-scalar values using a POST request, consider serializing them before transmission.

Could that be it?

Comment: Okay... I have to know how a runtime solution solved a compile-time problem. Can the OP please let us know what happened?